# Java String: Replace a string containing $ sign

Tags: java, regex

How can I replace a String `$1` in Java? I tried this, but this doesn't replace it:

```
System.out.println(someHTMLCodeAsString.replaceAll("$1", "REPLACED"));
```

Comment: You need to escape the $ with \\$ ;),  $ means end of the string and you can't have something after it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The $ is being interpreted as regex instead of as a character (it means 'end of line'). Try `System.out.println(someHTMLCodeAsString.replaceAll("\\$1", "REPLACED"));`

Answer (score 3):

try

```
 System.out.println(someHTMLCodeAsString.replace("$1", "REPLACED"));
```

Answer (score 0):

From [Java API docs](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)):
"Note that backslashes () and ***dollar signs ($)*** in the replacement string may cause the results to be different than if it were being treated as a literal replacement string; see Matcher.replaceAll. Use Matcher.quoteReplacement(java.lang.String) to suppress the special meaning of these characters, if desired."

Answer (score 0):

You've gotten bits and pieces of a response. Peter Lawrey is correct. You need to escape the $ with a regex escape not a string escape, thus the double \.

System.out.println(someHTMLCodeAsString.replaceAll("\\$1", "REPLACED"));

Comment: I realized that the other person ended up with the same problem with stackoverflow needing a double escaping \\\\ in order to make \\. So he deserves the +1.

Answer (score 0):

Or, let the regex library handle it for you:

```
someHTMLCodeAsString.replaceAll(Pattern.quote("$1"), "REPLACED")
```

Answer (score 0):

You Can Simply use this method:

```
someHTMLCodeAsString.replaceAll("\\$1", "REPLACED").
```

That replace All "$" to "REPLACED" simply!